# Google Sheets - Summing a range that requires a VLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table that accounts for certain items a player (P1, P2, etc) in a game has -

| name | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 |  | 1 |  |
| B |  |  |  |  |
| C | 1 |  |  | 1 |
| D |  | 1 |  | 1 |
| E | 3 |  | 2 |  |

and I have a table of values for those items -

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 4 |
| D | 1 |
| E | 5 |

How can I sum the total value of items each player has using a single formula? I'm having trouble getting VLOOKUP, SUM, FILTER, etc to work well together.

Example output:

| name | total value |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | 39 |
| P2 | 1 |
| P3 | 20 |
| P4 | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

try:

`=TRANSPOSE({{B1:1};BYCOL(B2:6,LAMBDA(bex,IF(COUNTA(bex)=0,,SUMPRODUCT(bex,{10;5;4;1;5}))))})`

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE({B1:E1; BYCOL(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 IF(B2:E="",,A2:A), G2:H, 2, )*B2:E), LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))}))
```

[image]